# How to multiply or add the values of a dictionary if the value of the dictionary is a list

Tags: python, dictionary

```
import csv

ratings_file = open("ratings.txt","r")
book_file = open("booklist.txt","r")
ratinglist = open("ratings.txt").readlines()
booklist = open("booklist.txt").readlines()
keys = [key.strip('\n') for key in ratinglist[0::2]]
values = [value.strip(' \n').split(' ') for value in ratinglist[1::2]]
my_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(my_dict)
```

My dictionary:

```
{'Nathan': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-5', '0', '5', '1', '0', '0', 
            '0', '1', '0', '5', '0', '-3', '0', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 
            '0', '-5', '0', '0', '-3', '5', '0', '5', '0', '3', '0', '0', '1', 
            '0', '3', '1', '3', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '-5', '0', 
            '0', '0', '0']}
```

I have this dictionary that has a key that is a name, and then the value is a list of values.

I'm wondering if it is possible to add all of the values to the associated key and make it into another dicitonary with a value of keys.

For instance, I was wondering if I could do this:

```
'Nathan' : ['241']
```

instead of all of the values being the different integers

I know how to add all of the values together for a list, or a dictionary, but I dont understand how to do it for a dictionary with a list of values.

Thanks

Comment: Something like [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum)?

Comment: Well yes, but I was wondering how I would do that for a dictionary that has a list inside of each value..

Comment: Why not simply store `sum(values)` immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Utilising `sum()` and `type()` can achieve this.

```
d = { 'test': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }

result = {key: sum(value) for key, value in d.items() if type(value) is list}

#{'test': 15}
```

If you input is strings, you can change `sum(value)` to `sum(map(int, value))`

This will iterate over every `key, value` pair in the dictionary, check if the value is a list, and `sum()` the result if `True`.

To Multiply, you can import `numpy` and change the above to;

```
import numpy as np
result = {key: np.prod(value) for key, value in d.items() if type(value) is list}

#{'test': 120}
```

Comment: now, could I multiply them instead if I would like? is there a multiply() function?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert all of the stings to integers before summing.

```
new_dict = {
    k: [str(sum(map(int, v)))] for k, v in my_dict.items()
}
```

To multiply, you can use the `reduce` function:

```
from functools import reduce

new_dict = {
    k: [str(reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, 
                   map(int, v) ))] 
    for k, v in my_dict.items()
}
```

Comment: now, could I multiply them instead if I would like? is there a multiply() function?

Answer (score 0):

First you should convert those strings to `int`, so :

```
my_dict['Nathan'] = [int(element) for element in my_dict['Nathan']]
```

then you add them up to make the final result :

```
my_dict['Nathan'] = sum(my_dict['Nathan'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
d = {'Nathan': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-5', '0', '5', '1', '0', '0', 
        '0', '1', '0', '5', '0', '-3', '0', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 
        '0', '-5', '0', '0', '-3', '5', '0', '5', '0', '3', '0', '0', '1', 
        '0', '3', '1', '3', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '-5', '0', 
        '0', '0', '0']}
```

Do

```
d2 = {k: str(sum(map(int, v))) for k, v in d.items()}
```

If you want to multiply all items in list do

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

a = [2, 5, 7, 9]
answer = reduce(mul, a)  # 2 * 5 * 7 * 9 = 630
```

Comment: now, could I multiply them instead if I would like? is there a multiply() function?